# React-native / AWS API Gateway android issue

Tags: android, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api

I am trying to use react-native with aws api gateway. Same code ( pure JS ) works great on ios but on android it fails with 403 error.

```
var signedRequest={
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-amz-date": "20170918T134411Z",
    "Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAIBC7RQ7MFUIRO7QQ/20170918/ap-northeast-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=9fb6d4d4820024097f25aaa70648fxxx7a54a2db1a67d173189693dc073d0a0bac8",
    "x-amz-security-token": "AgoGb3JpZ2luEKn////////xxxG1iKJBHjjvZH0DxcSqE889Wb3Mv+8PwMqrRe/O5dFFmP+9bQj+fSwVIUvmBplKkQB62x/xTelGHoCEOPXpBWLjT2OAUaBXOti7UZyfyMNgg56/Z58yxk4o2/37xPLbhXfODaL8kydFV8IaPJjdbJIX+a0kXycPLBnVIBdukUp9cMVD27mWN41u3w0VP5J8YiMPzrDnwKtb0U37naoIaknMBqNBDkMGQyHal/TBJ3wjJvJWVntrJvex0QKD8rDLHjaoiIYjBd+a04m2pKsBQJ9WQl02TTCPgRp0bb1oARF2hz0Xpi45Ba6a6E9SAL07UcRShTwX6rmxi0dZ38mkSbBMjI45Xg8r/VaRZx6/OyCq3u+nq4bgLCOMKqb/80F"
  },
  "data": "{\"data\":{\"func\":\"checkIfFacebookSignupComplete\",\"data\":{}}}",
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/user/user"
}

var apiResponse=await fetch(signedRequest.url, {

  method: signedRequest.method,
  body: signedRequest.data,
  headers: signedRequest.headers,

})
console.log("Got api response : ", apiResponse)
```

On iOS it receives a http response 200. However, on android it fails with:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

```
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/dev/user/user

accept:application/json
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
host:uihw7hnkn7.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170918T134411Z

accept;content-type;host;x-amz-date
6b83b80f2875c2425c28b258886ad98603fd802095e35303a3c2a72528374fb5'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170918T134411Z
20170918/ap-northeast-1/execute-api/aws4_request
008853cdfba53255257d9169e1a9c05500d01299da9efd4695ac8c66cb31e5e7'
"
```

I have tried axios as well . and same result. ( ios works fine, android fails ) I am using react-native 0.42.3.

Anyone got any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around a lot it appears the issue is related to as described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14445 . android okHttp library ( inernally used by react-native ) added charset=utf=8 to the request. So the solution is to calculate sig4 value with header like this:

```
  var signedRequest={
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "pplication/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-amz-date": "20170918T134411Z",
    "Authorization": "Calculated sig4 auth",
    "x-amz-security-token": "AgoGb3JpZ2luEKn////////xxxG1iKJBHjjvZH0DxcSqE889Wb3Mv+8PwMqrRe/O5dFFmP+9bQj+fSwVIUvmBplKkQB62x/xTelGHoCEOPXpBWLjT2OAUaBXOti7UZyfyMNgg56/Z58yxk4o2/37xPLbhXfODaL8kydFV8IaPJjdbJIX+a0kXycPLBnVIBdukUp9cMVD27mWN41u3w0VP5J8YiMPzrDnwKtb0U37naoIaknMBqNBDkMGQyHal/TBJ3wjJvJWVntrJvex0QKD8rDLHjaoiIYjBd+a04m2pKsBQJ9WQl02TTCPgRp0bb1oARF2hz0Xpi45Ba6a6E9SAL07UcRShTwX6rmxi0dZ38mkSbBMjI45Xg8r/VaRZx6/OyCq3u+nq4bgLCOMKqb/80F"
  },
  "data": "{\"data\":{\"func\":\"checkIfFacebookSignupComplete\",\"data\":{}}}",
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/user/user"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new AWS Amplify library (https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) on the official AWS repo has support for automatic signing to API Gateway. This is part of the API module: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/api_guide.md

You would first install the React Native npm module:

```
npm install aws-amplify-react-native
```

Then link the project: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development

After that you can configure APIs:

```
import Amplify, { API } from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure(
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',     //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
    },
    API: {
        endpoints: [
            {
                name: "ApiName1",
                endpoint: "https://1234567890-abcdefgh.amazonaws.com"
            },
            {
                name: "ApiName2",
                endpoint: "https://1234567890-abcdefghijkl.amazonaws.com"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Following that your API Gateway requests are signed using the user's credentials:

```
let apiName = 'MyApiName';
let path = '/path'; 
let myInit = { // OPTIONAL
    headers: {} // OPTIONAL
}
API.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with the same issue. `GET` worked on both platforms, but `POST` only on iOS. Setting `Content-Type` to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` before signing the request with [sigV4Client](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/sigV4Client) fixed it for me.

```
const path = 'https://your-aws-endpoint.com';
const method = 'POST';
const queryParams = {};
const body = {};
const headers = {
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
};

const client = sigV4Client.newClient({
    accessKey: ACCESS_KEY,
    secretKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: SESSION_TOKEN,
    region: REGION,
    endpoint: ENDPOINT,
});

const signedRequest = client.signRequest({
    method: method,
    path: path,
    headers: headers,
    queryParams: queryParams,
    body: body
});

fetch(signedRequest.url, {
    method: method,
    headers: signedRequest.headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then((results) => {
    ...
});
```